# add string text to the right of each bar. how to do it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

[image]

```
.chart div {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}

</style>
<div class="chart"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var data = [1.19209289551e-05, 3.70760703087, 0.162719964981, 0.159816026688, 0.159816026688, 6.00016117096];

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, 1024]);

d3.select(".chart")
  .selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")
    .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

</script>
```

Based on this code,I want to add string text to the right of each bar. how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/)?

Comment: Bit of a roundabout way to do this, but replace `.text(...)` with `.append("div").text(function (d) {return d;}).style("margin-left", function (d) {return x(d) + 3 + "px";}).style("background-color", "white").style("color", "black");` This will append a div the width of the bar plus the padding (3px) to the right of the original bar, and then add the text into this div.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.chart div {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}

</style>
<div class="chart"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var data = [1.19209289551e-05, 3.70760703087, 0.162719964981, 0.159816026688, 6.00016117096];
var data_tex =   {1.19209289551e-05 :'getCurrentID' , 3.70760703087: 'initialize OPK', 0.162719964981 :'GetSharedData', 0.159816026688 :'SetSharedData',  6.00016117096:'Synchronize resource'};

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, 1024]);

d3.select(".chart")
  .selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")
    .style("width", function(d) { return x(d)+ "px"; })
    .append("div").text(function (d) {return data_tex[d] + ": " + d + "s";}).style("margin-left", function (d) {return x(d) + 3 + "px";}).style("background-color", "white").style("color", "brown");;

</script>
```

Thanks to JSBob, this is perfect for me.